# Regex with lookaround to find group of numbers is inconclusive

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a hierachical folder structure, which builds upon a nestes asset / project hierachy.

- The Top Level Assets have their Id in paranthesis `Foo (22)`. (2 - n digits -enclosed in parenthesis)
- Level 2 then looks like this: `Foo (22^108)` (2 groups of 2-n digits divided by ^ and enclosed in parenthesis)
- Level 3: `Foo (22^108^1771)`
- Level 4: ...
- Level 5: ...
- Project Level: `(^123)` ^ + 2-n digits enclosed by paranthesis

I need to traverse this folder structure, and move certain hierachy levels to other destinations.

To identify on which on which hierachiy level I am currently on and where the current folder needs to be moved, I want to use regular expressions.

I have got my expressions ready for the levels 1 through 4 and the project level, but Level 5 is inconclusive and I can't figure out why.

Given the following 2 examples ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c2ejDj/2)):

1. Level 4 (22^108^581^2116)
2. Foo, Kings Road Level 5 (22^108^581^2116^7310)

The regex `\((?<!\^)(\d{2,}\^{0,1}){4}(?!\^)\)` matches only the level 4 asset, which is correct.
The regex for level 5 is similar: `\((?<!\^)(\d{2,}\^{0,1}){5}(?!\^)\)` - I am increasing the amount of capturing groups from 4 to 5, but according to regex it matches level 4 as well as 5, which should not happen.
So the goal is to match the following pattern:

1. Opening parenthesis
2. 5 groups of 2 to n digits
3. the groups are divided a Caret
4. The first group must not have a leading Caret
5. The last group must not have a trailing Caret
6. closing Parenthesis

What did I do wrong?

PS: If it is of any importance. The folders reside in a SharePoint document library and the code will run in Powershell.

Comment: Can we see how you are executing the regex and evaluating success/failure?

Comment: As of now I have been using regex101.com to test and simple Powershell calls a la: `"Foo (22^108^581^2116)" -match "\((?<!\^)(\d{2,}\^{0,1}){4}(?!\^)\)"`

Comment: `\((?<!\^)(\d{2,}\^){4}\d{2,}(?!\^)\)`. Why not just something like that? The carets have to be there in the middle so dont use `{0,1}`. I don't even think you need the look behinds. `\((\d{2,}\^){4}\d{2,}\)`

Comment: That should work for level 5 - cool :) And I can adapt 2 - 4 as well. even better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to worry about criteria 4 and 5 the way you are. As long as the leading bracket is followed by digits and the last bracket is also preceeded by digits you should be fine.

```
\((\d{2,}\^){4}\d{2,}\)
```

Matches the outside braces as well as 4 groups of digits and a trailing caret as well as one last group of digits. If you are looking to match level 3 then change the 4 to 2 in the above regex.

It there was leading or trailing carets they would not be matched.

### Named Matches

Depending on how you are using these values later it might be beneficial to looks at named matches in PowerShell. What we are going to do it build a custom regex match string based on the number of levels that you are trying to match against.

```
$matchNumberOfLevels = 5
$regex = "\(" + 
    ((1..($matchNumberOfLevels-1) | ForEach-Object{"(?<level$_>\d{2,})\^"}) -join "") +
    "(?<level$matchNumberOfLevels>\d{2,})\)"

"Foo, Kings Road Level 5 (22^108^581^2116^7310)" -match $regex
```

For each of those levels (1 to 5 in the example above) we make a named match called level_n_ where *n* is the position of the caret delimited number. So then we you look at matches you will get named matches that you can use later in your code.

```
$matches

Name                           Value                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                 
level3                         581                                                                                                   
level2                         108                                                                                                   
level4                         2116                                                                                                  
level5                         7310                                                                                                  
level1                         22                                                                                                    
0                              (22^108^581^2116^7310) 

$matches.level1
22
```

Cool but might be overboard.

### Split result

A simple trim and split would get something simlar just not with the fancy names.

```
$matchNumberOfLevels = 5
"Foo, Kings Road Level 5 (22^108^581^2116^7310)" -match "\((\d{2,}\^){$($matchNumberOfLevels - 1)}\d{2,}\)"
$levels = $Matches[0].Trim("()") -split "\^"
$levels[0]
```

So `$levels` is an array with 5 elements corresponding to the level of you system.

Note this logic fails for level 1 only matches.

Comment: Matt, how comes the irritating ordering of the $matches output? The $regex is ordered straight forward. `\((?<level1>\d{2,})\^(?<level2>\d{2,})\^(?<level3>\d{2,})\^(?<level4>\d{2,})\^(?<level5>\d{2,})\)`?

Comment: @LotPings I know it has to do with how PS handles hashtables. Don't have the exact reason handy right now. It's related to why they introduced `[ordered]`. For the most part its just how it gets displayed